# Rotate photo in Mergin Maps preview

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

I am setting up a Mergin Maps project and would like an image taken from the QGIS Photo widget to display in the preview. I have been able to get the photo to show up in the preview using the following code:

```
# image
file:///[%@project_folder%]/[% 'FolderName' %]/[% "Photo" %]
```

However, I would like it to auto-rotate like the image does in the photo widget in the Features menu. How might I do this?

Additionally, I have not been able to combine the image with text data from other fields in the preview using the `#fields` code suggested here: https://merginmaps.com/docs/gis/features/#settings-for-mergin-maps-input-preview-panel. Is it possible to combine field data and image data in the preview, and if so, how might this be done?

Comment: This bug should be already fixed in latest version

Answer (score 0):

I have raised a ticket for image rotation and should be addressed in the next release:
https://github.com/MerginMaps/input/issues/2632

You are right: it is not possible to combine image and text with Image tag. It should be possible to have images as HTML tag, but I am not able to get the scaling works properly.